# [UIDeviceRGBColor countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16577e10 -> A Crash After makeKeyAndVisible

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, xcode8, nsexception

I get the following error when debug and found that after this line, the app crash:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When attempt to run on device via Xcode 8.0, the following error log appears:

> 2016-10-03 11:03:59.827994 Slots[5972:1125279] -[UIDeviceRGBColor
>   countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x16577e10
>
> 2016-10-03 11:03:59.830292 Slots[5972:1125279] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIDeviceRGBColor countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16577e10'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (0x1db25e07 0x1cd8b077 0x1db2b515 0x1db29589 0x1da4ef08 0x2303d18d 0x23037bff 0x1e3b39a5 0x1e3b2e6d
>   0x23047fc9 0x23048641 0x1e3b39a5 0x1e3b9d3d 0x1e354ca7 0x1e3b39a5
>   0x1e3b2e6d 0x23047507 0x22ec2589 0x22c9eecb 0x22b6b067 0x22b6af9f
>   0x22b716a3 0x22b6eb9d 0x22be1051 0xc3cf1 0x22bdd33b 0x22de9e01
>   0x22def41f 0x22e01fc5 0x22dec805 0x1f3ea97b 0x1f3ea835 0x1f3eab1f
>   0x1dae1c8b 0x1dae1795 0x1dadfa6b 0x1da2f073 0x1da2ee81 0x22bd6b69
>   0x22bd1201 0xc398f 0x1d1fa50b)
>   **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

Any ideas what might be causing this crash. I have no storyboards, only xibs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same issue with `iOS 10`,`xcode8` while loading view or initializing view from/or using `xib's`.

You can try following solution:

1. Go to your interface files, means `Xib's` and `Nib's`.
2. On the right side, navigate to the ***File Inspector*** tab.
3. Change the value for ***"Build for"*** to "iOS 7.0 and Later" or any other iOS version and later.
4. Clean, Rebuild and Run project.

Check image for reference:

[image: img]

Comment: Great...HTH, mark answer accepted if it helped to solve problem so, it can help others having same issue@itzo.

Answer (score 0):

When I opened my iOS 6 project  in Xcode 8.3.1. I had this error when I run a build for iOS 9.1 and above.

Opening nib files and changing in interface builder document option "Builds for" option to "iOS 7.0 and later" solved this issue.